# Is there a way to make a temporary/non-persistent registry edit?

Tags: python, windows, scripting

I'm looking to make a registry change from the raw code/script level, however, I would like to make it temporary and not permanent. For example, when the program is finished running, the registry edit would no longer exist. Is this possible, or would it come down to having the program save the current registry config, then reverting the changes at the end of the program?

Comment: If you are open to calling the win32 api directly you should also add the `winapi` tag. Perhaps [RegOverridePredefKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regoverridepredefkey) and/or [REG_OPTION_VOLATILE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regcreatekeyexw) might be of interest.

Comment: Please post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve so people can get to help you

Comment: If you're setting a value in an existing, persistent key, then no, the value cannot be made temporary. If it's a new key that you create, then the key can be made volatile, which means it will persist as long as the parent hive is loaded. There is no equivalent to the file API's delete-on-close flag.